# How to remove columns have Nan at the first row

Tags: python, null, nan

[image]I have several datas.The first row has some elements is Nan, thus, I will remove them. Then, the following dataframe should delete columns corresponding. Hereunder is example of my dataframe. Please advise how I can remove columns have Nan at the first row.

```
        Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 NaN Var5 NaN Var6 NaN
Values  10   20   30   40   50  60   70  80   90
Values  10   20   30   40   x   60   y   80   z
Values  10   20   30   40   a   60   b   80   c
```

I have an idea, that is I will put Columns have NaN (in the first row) to the last columns, then, I remove them. However, I would like to get the flexible way because I'm not sure how much 'Nan' elements in the first row. I used many methods but not sucessful. X is name of DataFrame:
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

```
dirname=askopenfilename( initialdir='/.log', title= 'please select a directory')
j=pd.read_csv(dirname, header=None, sep=r";")
if None in x.ix[0]:
    y = x.drop([col for col in x if col in x.ix[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Expected output:

```
        Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 
Values  10   20   30   40   60   80   
Values  10   20   30   40   60   80   
Values  10   20   30   40   60   80
```

Comment: where is your code/effort? what is the database and how you are accessing it?

Comment: I just updated my question. Actually, I tried many ways but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `df`:

```
        Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 NaN Var5 NaN Var6 NaN
Values  10   20   30   40   50  60   70  80   90
Values  10   20   30   40   x   60   y   80   z
Values  10   20   30   40   a   60   b   80   c
```

Then you can drop columns whose name is `NaN`:

```
df = df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.strip()=='NaN'], axis=1)
df
```

it will be:

```
        Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6
Values  10      20      30      40      60      80
Values  10      20      30      40      60      80
Values  10      20      30      40      60      80
```

**Update:**

based on your update, your df is:

```
    0     1     2     3     4   5     6   7    8
0   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  NaN Var5  NaN Var6 NaN
1   10    20    30    40    50  60    70  80   90
2   10    20    30    40    x   60    y   80    z
3   10    20    30    40    a   60    b   80    c
```

Then you can set row 0 to be columns name and filter based on column name is not nan:

```
import numpy as np
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col is not np.nan]]
df
```

df will be:

```
    Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6
0   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6
1   10    20    30    40    60    80
2   10    20    30    40    60    80
3   10    20    30    40    60    80
```

Comment: My DataFrame hasn't from read_fwf(.csv). When I tried, it got error: `'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: what's your df? it seems that you compare incorrectly for the column names. can you get the column name of your df?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new of code. My df come from read_csv:`from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
dirname=askopenfilename( initialdir='/.log', title= 'please select a directory')
j=pd.read_csv(dirname, header=None, sep=r";") df=j.ix[:, 2:612]`

Comment: My df keeps as same, doesn't change.

Comment: I make a df same as yours, then drop columns whose name == `NaN`

Comment: I tried again,and it happened for Var1, var2 ... but 'NaN'. When read my file as df, Its happen the column headers. Unnamed: 4, 5, 6 (number of column) `df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col=='Var 2 '], axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: please share your file

Comment: I suspect your column name for `NaN` with some blank space, need `strip()` it like this: `df = df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.strip()=='NaN'], axis=1)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know to share file. i just added the photo and I would like to remove columns: 4, 6, 8.

Comment: Columns '4', '6', '8' is for example. My data has about more than 600 columns and they're randomly.

Comment: @NguyenTram then you can set your df row 0 to be column name, then filter df based on column name is not nan, check the updated answer.

Comment: Somehow, I don't know why it doesn't work in my case. Then, I used `df.drop([col for col in df.columns if "Unnamed" in col], axis=1, inplace=True)`. Many thanks.

Comment: it means your df column name is not `nan`, but `Unnamed`. And glad you solve your issue, cheers :)